# reading a variable in method marked @Parameterized.Parameters

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I have a method marked with annotation @Parameterized.Parameters

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static List<Object[]> myData() {
```

Now as part of another method marked with  @BeforeClass, I read SystemProperty xyz

```
@BeforeClass
final String xyz = System.getProperty("XYZ");
```

If there anyway I can use xyz in myData so get List which depends on xyz? Something like making sure that Parameters are populated only after BeforeClass is done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set only "xyz" String  - don't use `@BeforeClass` because it can be used only on static methods (your example is actually not correct).

So, define "xyz" as static final without @BeforeClass annotation:

```
private static final String xyz = System.getProperty("XYZ");
```

It would be accessible in `myData()` with value from that property.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get the value inside `myData()` if you set "xyz" inside static method with `@BeforeClass` because that method would be invoked after `myData()` (in that case "xyz" would be null). As a workaround you can use static initialization block instead.